# Is this Eshonai or Dalinar on the cover of The Way of Kings?

Tags: character-identification, cosmere, stormlight-archive, cover-art

Michael Whelan’s very nice cover for *The Way of Kings* depicts two characters in the Shattered Plains. One in the right foreground is wearing Shardplate with alight red cloak with a somewhat crab-like pattern on it, holding a long Shardblade and a tall triangular flag with a crab symbol that I don’t remember ever being described in the book. The other is far away, holding a very tall spear and a shield.

The one in the background seems to be Kaladin. However, I’m not sure who the person in the foreground is. **Is the character in the front of the cover Dalinar, or is it Eshonai?**

[image: An image of the relevant part of the cover]

Comment: The cover looks like an homage to Bruce Pennington. Compare e.g. with this one:
https://www.blackgate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Bruce-Pennington-Dune.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently Michael Whelan's assistant [tweeted recently](https://twitter.com/whelanmichael/status/1295733129995595776) to set the record straight that it's not Dalinar:

> Just to clarify some misconceptions I've seen in Stormlight Archive discussions. That's not Dalinar on the cover of THE WAY OF KINGS.

And according to [a follow-up tweet](https://twitter.com/whelanmichael/status/1295741147877441539?s=19) neither of them are supposed to be characters:

> Not a literal interpretation of any character.  The cover was  meant to convey the conflict at the Shattered Plains.

Answer (score 10):

### It is Dalinar in the foreground, and Eshonai in the background.

From a reading that Brandon Sanderson did way back when:

> I’ve been reading from the viewpoint of someone named Eshonai at other readings I’ve done last week. And Eshonai is Parshendi. **If you’ve read the Way of Kings, those who have, Eshonai is actually the character on the cover. Someone wanna hold up Way of Kings? So one of those figures is Dalinar and the other is Eshonai, according to Michael Whalen. There is a scene where Dalinar raises his sword acrossed the chasm toward a Parshendi Shardbearer.** And later on Dalinar faces this Parshendi Shardbearer and has a good old slogfest, near the end of the book, between two Shardbearers pounding on each other. And this character, I’ve always intended to, later on, get some viewpoints and I’ve been writing from her viewpoint in the second book.

Sourced from [this document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-y8Jv2apfo_0THOnPxoyHP_8FCE_0TplwXzVR4qH9UQ/edit), via [this forum post](https://www.17thshard.com/forum/topic/5878-wok-cover-explanation/?do=findComment&comment=93324)

Comment: [Audio of the WoB.](https://www.17thshard.com/interviews/SA%20Eshonai%20Part%202.mp3)

Comment: I always assumed it was actually Eshonai in the foreground because if it's Dalinar, his house color is wrong (it should be blue not red), but the general consensus is that it's Dalinar in the foreground, Eshonai in the background.

Comment: Dalinar is the one raising his sword in the scene the cover is taken from. Also, Dalinar is a main character in the book, while Eshonai is only a faceless enemy at this point.  Symbolically it makes no sense for her to be in the foreground.  Besides, epic fantasy covers have a grand tradition of misdressing their characters.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus It is somewhat unusual in a Whelan cover, though, his work is normally meticulously grounded in the text.

Comment: The crab heraldic doesn't make sense for Dalinar though. He would be wearing blue and white, the sigil would be a tower above a crown.

Comment: So I guess that the question is: is the error in this artwork the scene composition (incorrect viewpoint, and wrong person raising the sword) or in costuming (colors and sigil)?  I'm inclined to think that the scene composition is accurate, but there's no real basis for that determination.

Comment: Yes, there is a scene like that where they greet each other across a chasm, so the costuming is off. I also don't remember if Eshonai used a sword or a spear.